# Topic Modeling Using Gensim in Python

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, lda, gensim

I have a list of bag of words for two classes. Say ***n*** items in class ***A*** and ***m*** items in class ***B***. I want to use the topic modeling with gensim package (for LDA) in python in order to train a model for class A vs class B. Meanwhile I am new to both **Topic Modeling** and **Python**. Does anyone know how should I do this? I mean, should I merge all the bags for each class and the use gensim or should I use bag for each item seperately? Thanks!

Comment: In the vanilla LDA topic model, documents are assumed to be generated by drawing from bags of words, so the bags of words are the topic models, roughly speaking. What do you mean by a list of bags of words?

Comment: What I am asking is that if I have 2 instances for label A and 3 instances for label B, should I just merge instances for each group or give them to gensim model individually? each instance is a bag of words. For example ([0, 2, 2, 0, A], [1, 2, 1, 1, A], [3, 0, 0, 1, B], [3, 3, 0, 0, B]). Should I use these two or merge 2 for A as [1, 4, 3, 1, A] and merge for B as [6, 3, 0, 1, B] and now only use these two?

Comment: Okay, so the bag-of-words you are talking about is the unigram representation that gensim calls `bow`. A simple thing you can do is to first train one LDA model for A and another for B on a training partition (say, 80% of the bows of each class). On the remaining 20%, or ``the test set", which you have for both A and B, use the topic models to calculate the probability of each document; the one that produces the highest probability will have its label assigned to the document being tested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you want to compare documents from two sources.

One way to do this with Gensim would be:

- create bag of words corpus from all documents (A and B) (~convert texts to a n X n matrix of ones and zeroes)
- train LDA model on your corpus (~ find the topics)
- convert corpus to LDA space (~ determine which topics are relevant for the documents)

Now you can see topics distributions for each documents and determine how similar two documents are using Gensim's similarity methods.

For details take a look at Gensim's [tutorials](http://radimrehurek.com/gensim/tutorial.html). The only modification you'd need to make would be to combine your documents from A and B into one bigger document and save the indices somewhere so that you can compare them easily later.

However, depending on your data and your goal, other forms of LDA (such as correlated topics models) may be more suitable.

Comment: Actually, List A is the abstracts from group of articles A and B is the list of abstracts for group of papers B. I have an article represented with a list (bag of words). for example : [1, 2, 0, 0, A], [0, 2, 2, 0, A] and [1, 0, 0, 4, B].
Now given bag of words for an abstract of unknown journal (like [0, 3, 1, 0, ?]) I want to figure out which group of articles it came from!

Comment: In that case the approach suggested by Lord Henry Wotton might work. Or train one model over all files and use document similarity to classify. Perhaps you should also take a look at dedicated classification algorithms, Scikit-Learn may be a good starting point.